# Wordpress / css / align diagonal line in header and slider

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress site with the Enfold theme. The design i have to make has an important design feature, which you can see here: [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXlge.jpg)

The feature I mean is the diagonal line that starts in the header and goes through the slider.

Not really a problem, but the problems start on different screen sizes. The line in the header and slider should line out at all times.

This is what I have so far: http://msnw.thinktwice.nl/.

The line in the header and in the slider are 2 transparant images.

To see better what is going on I made the diagonal line in the slider in red.

It's not perfect at the moment. The diagonal line should start next to the logo and stay next to the logo on different screen sizes.

I also tried to combine the logo and the diagonal line in one image. Then the line always stays next to the logo. However the diagonal line in the slider then doesn't line out.

Any idea's how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I played a little bit with this.

Try to:
remove `background-position` in `.ls-gpuhack` and change `left` to eg. `left: 19% !important;`

Comment: I changed .ls-gpuhack to:

.ls-gpuhack { 
 background-image: url(http://msnw.thinktwice.nl/wp-content/themes/enfold-child/images/slider_foreground.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 left: 19% !important;
}

Is that what you mean? What do I do with the header image?

Comment: why don't you provide link to original layout?

Comment: Well the Original layout is just a PSD file from the designer.

Comment: Anyone have an idea?

Comment: I doubt there is some javascript involved in. Try to find it.